# Can someone explain how the induction step is carried out in this proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation

[image]

I do not understand the part where it says that 
as $k \geq 3$ we can go from $2^k + 2$ to $2^k + 2^k$.

Comment: $c\gt d$ and $a=b\implies a+d\lt b+c$

Comment: Take $a=b=2^k$ and $c=2^k$ and $d=2$. $2^k\gt 2$ as $k\ge3$

Answer (score 1):

He said this reason for the step before this one, i.e. he meant that as $k\ge 3$ then from our assumption in the induction we have $2k+1 \le 2^k$.

But the step after it is always true, I mean $2 \le 2^k$ for any $k\ge 1$ (which is the same as saying $2^k+2\le 2^k+2^k$)

Answer (score 1):

$2\leq 2^k$ for all $k\geq 3$.

In fact, this is true for all $k\geq1$, but we have specifically chosen $k$ to be 3 or more in this proof.